# How to await when all Monos from List are finished(doesn't matter succesfully or not)

Tags: java, concurrency, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-reactive

I have such code:

```
List<Mono> monoList = foo();
//await when all Monos are finished
try {
    Flux.fromIterable(monoList)
            .flatMap(Function.identity())
            .then()
            .block();

} catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("error", e);
}
```

It works perfect when all MONO are finished successfully but doesn't work if at least onee Mono finished with error. Method `block` throw exceptions and interrupts all other monos. So this code awaits when all mono are finished successfully or when the first error happen.

How to await when all Monos from `monoList` are finished(doesn't matter succesfully or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
  try {
        Flux.fromIterable(monoList)
                .flatMap(Function.identity())
                .then()
                .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> {
                    //just ignore it we've already caught all errors
                })
                .block();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Polling finished with exceptions", e);
    }
```

Comment: dont use try catch in a reactive world, try catch is blocking, errors should be handled in the code flow instead

Comment: I did it just to make sure that this code doesn't throw exception